# In AWS what is threadhold value for Average write latency for EBS volume GP3

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a EBS volume with Average write latency at about 3 and above. This EBS had the following details

> Size 1000GB General Purpose SSD GP3 IOPS 3000 Throughput 125

Is 3ms/op very high? Would increasing the IPOs help in reducing Average write latency. The file system is XFS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is 3ms/op very high?

Compared to what?

> Would increasing the [IOPs] help in reducing Average write latency.

Do the sums.

Currently you have 3ms latency for a single IOP. There are 333 3ms windows in 1 second, yet your device is supposed to support 3000 IOPs. There is no contradiction here; they can overlap and/or be processed in parallel - i.e. with multiple threads working flat out, you will get close to 3000 IOPs until you saturate the bandwidth.

So it depends on your workload.

But.....who cares?

What matters is

1. How much it costs you - more IOPs will cost you more
2. Whether your application has better performance and/or capacity - you can make informed guesses if you know your application and workload inside out (we can't) but you really need to determine the answer experimentally.